# How can I create a struct that takes an iterator?

Tags: generics, rust

I would like to create a struct that can hold any kind of iterator. A simplified attempt of my actual code is below:

```
struct MyStruct<I> {
    my_iter: I,
}

impl<I> MyStruct<I>
where 
    I: std::iter::Iterator<Item = usize>,
{
    fn new(start: usize) -> Self {
        let v: Vec<usize> = vec![start+1, start+2, start+3];
        Self {
            my_iter: v.iter().map(|n| n*2),
        }
    }
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7c7c68dff49b280bb639738233d357fd

Unfortunately I get the following error on compilation:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:12:22
   |
5  | impl<I> MyStruct<I>
   |      - this type parameter
...
12 |             my_iter: v.iter().map(|n| n*2),
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter `I`, found struct `Map`
   |
   = note: expected type parameter `I`
                      found struct `Map<std::slice::Iter<'_, usize>, [closure@src/main.rs:12:35: 12:42]>`

error[E0284]: type annotations needed: cannot satisfy `<_ as Iterator>::Item == usize`
  --> src/main.rs:18:13
   |
18 |     let _ = MyStruct::new(2);
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot satisfy `<_ as Iterator>::Item == usize`
   |
note: required by a bound in `MyStruct::<I>::new`
  --> src/main.rs:7:28
   |
7  |     I: std::iter::Iterator<Item = usize>,
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `MyStruct::<I>::new`
8  | {
9  |     fn new(start: usize) -> Self {
   |        --- required by a bound in this

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0284, E0308.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0284`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to 2 previous errors
```

I can't figure out from the error how to get what I want.

Comment: Nitpick: `Iterator` is in the prelude, you don't have to qualify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with your implementation:

- The `.iter()` method **borrows** the vec, thus you are trying to store a reference to local variable, which is incorrect (use after free)
- The generics are driven from "outside", but you want to specify them from inside the function, which is not possible.

So one option is to use a boxed iterator. This would allow you to both specify it from withing the function body and also use **any** iterator:

```rust
struct MyStruct {
    my_iter: Box<dyn Iterator<Item = usize>>,
}

impl MyStruct {
    fn new(start: usize) -> Self {
        let v: Vec<usize> = vec![start + 1, start + 2, start + 3];
        Self {
            // note that we are using `.into_iter()` which does not borrow the vec, but converts it to an iterator!
            my_iter: Box::new(v.into_iter().map(|n| n * 2)),
        }
    }
}
```

Another option, if you insist on using generics, is to pass the iterator from outside:

```rust
use std::marker::PhantomData;

struct MyStruct<'l, I> {
    my_iter: I,
    _phantom: PhantomData<&'l I>,
}

impl<'l, I> MyStruct<'l, I>
where
    I: std::iter::Iterator<Item = usize> + 'l,
{
    fn new(iter: I) -> Self {
        Self {
            my_iter: iter,
            _phantom: Default::default(),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut data = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let x = MyStruct::new(data.iter().map(|x| *x + 1));
}
```

Comment: Notably in the example given by OP there is also a [third option](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=08ac7aab43ad8a5606c14920f88bdb22) of storing the precise iterator type (`std::iter::Map<std::vec::IntoIter<usize>, fn(usize) -> usize>`) in MyStruct, but this quickly gets unwieldy.

Comment: @apilat OP wants to hold **any** kind of iterator, so specifying the exact type is a no-go.

Comment: OP *says* they want to hold any kind of iterator but in the example given they only ever store one type, so my approach does apply. You're definitely right that it doesn't work if their unsimplified code needs to use multiple iterator types.